# Divs heights in %

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with divs height. I set this value in %.
Divs parent height is set in js and is 100% window height - navbar height.

Everything is ok but when I click for example CTRL + '-' somethng breaks down.

How can I fix it?

I attach screenshots to know what's going on.

When zoom in browser is 100%:
[image]

When zoom in browser is 90%:
[image]

```js
var onResize = function() {

  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
if (windowWidth >= 992) {
// Set height for full-height-inner
   if ($('.full-height-inner').length > 0) {
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
//var navbarHeight = $('#navbar-wrapper').outerHeight();
  var navbarHeight = '79px';
  $('.full-height-inner').css('height', (windowHeight - navbarHeight));
}
} else {
// Reset height for full-height-inner
   if ($('.full-height-inner').length > 0) {
  $('.full-height-inner').css('height', 'auto');
}
}
};

$(document).ready(function() {
// Events when window resize
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
onResize();
});

// Events when window is loaded
        $(window).on('load', function() {
onResize();
});
});
```

```html
<link href="http://imd.imd.com.pl/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="full-height w-100 fl relative">
<div class="full-height-inner dt-md w-100">
 <div class="right dtc-md w-100 w-50-md fl fn-md relative v-top-md">
  <div class="gallery w-100 fl relative">
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="gallery-item fl relative cf">
    <a href="#" class="w-100 fl">
     <figure class="gallery-photo w-100 pa0 fl ma0 relative">
      <img src="#" class="db mw-100 mw-none-md">
      <figcaption class="photo-description w-100 absolute">
       <div class="photo-description-inner w-100 tc ph4 absolute">
        <h3 class="mv0"><span>Title</span></h3>
        <p class="mt2 mb0"><span>Description</span></p>
       </div>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you're trying to keep it responsive, you don't want to be setting a % on the height. height should be `auto`

Comment: I have to set the height in% because the parent has a certain height, and all children must occupy 100% of his height.

Comment: Perhaps look into using flexbox with this, it would help greatly.